# Daily notices of failed login attempts for non-existent admin user

Tags: admin, login

I run a multi-user site and for the past week or two I have been getting daily notices that someone is getting locked out due to failed login attempts for user "admin" via the [Limit Login Attempts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/limit-login-attempts/) plugin.

There is no user account for "admin" and I assume this is an attack in an attempt to gain access to the wp-admin section of the site.

I'm assuming if there is no "admin" user, then these attempts will never be successful.

Am I safe to disregard these notices since there is no user named "admin" or are there other measures I can take to safeguard my site from being accessed maliciously?

The attempts have been from a few different IP addresses so blocking the IP would only temporarily deter the behavior. Limiting the wp-admin to only specific IP addresses is not realistic due to the number of users that log in from different places.

Comment: In my case, all failed login attempts use `WooCommerce` user, from different IP addresses. My site also does not have `WooCommerce` user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can safely ignore it, especially if your site has no "admin" user. The brute-force attack will never accomplish anything. I also use Limit Login Attempts - mainly for this very purpose. It lets me know when manual brute-force attempts are being made on my back-end login. (Last time I bothered to WHOIS the IP, the attack was coming from Russia, FWIW.)

Short of blocking the IP address, there is little you can do to prevent brute-force attempts. If they get to be bothersome, just increase the lockout duration.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at Fail2Ban if you want to prevent people attempting other naughty things on your server, but I've just found a reference to this plugin that I'm about to investigate myself:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mute-screamer/

Comment: When my WordPress installation was flooded with login attempts they came from many different IP addresses. Blocking IP addresses after x failed attempts may not have an effect nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Captcha verification and temporary IP blocking will be provide extra security in our WordPress. These two feachers are providing by following plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-limit-login-attempts .